# Negative margin and scrollbars

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have something like this currently:

```
<div class = "className" style = "position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -500px;" >
```

This works just fine when the browser's window is large enough (more than 1000px wide), but when I resize it to a smaller width, part of the div overflows to the left and the scrollbar doesn't cover the overflowed area. I tried it on Firefox, Chrome and IE8, all result in the same symptoms. How can I fix this?
Here's a demo: http://pastehtml.com/view/bsanetaio.html (try resizing your browser window to a width smaller than 1000px  to see the problem).

Comment: What's the expected outcome? Do you have a live example, it's hard to decipher what you mean by "doesn't work."

Comment: Negative margins are a bad idea and should be avoided wherever possible.  To help better we'll need some more info though?

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks the content he has there is pulled back to the left by the negative margin. it's "overflowed" the screen to the left and there is no scrollbar towards the left.

Comment: I have three divs that need to be centered beside each other.

Comment: I'll add it to the demo for more clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should achieve the desired effect. Notice that the inner div does not have position absolute.

```
<div style="position: absolute; left:50%">
  <div style="width: 1000px; margin-left: -500px;">

  </div>
</div>
```

There may be a better way to do what you are trying to do though.

Comment: This is still resulting in the same overflow behavior. Can you please take a look at the demo?

Comment: Here is an [alternative way](http://uoco.net/d/dev/center_blocks.html) to get the same result. You could use `display: inline-block` instead of float if you want.

Comment: @Abody97 I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's better you can use `margin:0 auto` for center the content. It's better then **absolute**

Comment: I'm not trying to center the content, please take a look at the demo if you have time! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to achieve this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #container {
        margin: 0 auto;      /* if you want center the container */
        white-space: nowrap; /* get all divs on one line, don't need this if fixed width used */
        width: min-content;  /* you can use fixed size*/
      }
      #container div {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 10px;
        width: 320px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: gray;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="title"> Welcome! </div>
    <div id="container">
      <div> Data, data, data<br />data data, data </div>
      <div> Data, data, data<br />data data, data </div>
      <div> Data, data, data<br />data data, data </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```